# Rename an excel file, and check if a file exists in sharepoint through vba

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

So, I am building a userform which multiple people will fill. The common database file will be kept at the Sharepoint. The form works perfectly fine only until 2 people arent pressing submit button at the same time.

To counter this, this is what someone suggested me to do:

```
Sub DownloadAndSave()
' In the location in the network folder:
' If a file exists called "MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm" then
      'deny a save
' Else
      ' RENAME the target file to "MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm"
' Download "MyData_CHEKOUT.xlsm", make changes, save file to network as "MyData.xlsm"
' Delete the MyData_CHECKOUT.xlsm" file
End Sub
```

Earlier I was using a network drive and this was working fine. But for sharepoint I cant find a method to rename the file.
I have found ways to delete a sharepoint file, download and upload it.
But I cant find answers to rename the file, and to check if the file exists already in the sharepoint folder.

Please help, or if there is some other way to solve the issue of 2 people submitting at the same time, please guide me on that

Edit: The complete code I am using right now is:

```
Sub Submit()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    If frmForm.txtAE.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtAPL.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtBatches.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtProject.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtQA.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtTeam.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbDS.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbPriority.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbRelease.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Complete All fields marked with (*) to proceed")
    Else
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim strFileExists As String
        'Call Downloadtest
        strFileName = ""
        strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

        If strFileName <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Another user is currently submitting a booking. Please wait for a minute, and then try again.")
        Else

            Dim nwb As Workbook
            Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("sharepoint link")

            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="password"
            Dim emptyRow As Long
            emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1

            Dim arDate As Variant
            arDate = Split(frmForm.dtPlanned.Value, "/")
            With nwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = emptyRow - 1
                .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = Date
                .Cells(emptyRow, 3) = frmForm.txtProject.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 4) = frmForm.txtTeam.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 5) = frmForm.txtAPL.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 6) = frmForm.txtQA.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 7) = frmForm.txtAE.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 8) = frmForm.cmbRelease.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 9) = frmForm.cmbDS.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 10) = frmForm.txtBatches.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 11) = frmForm.dtReview.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 12) = frmForm.dtSubmission.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 13) = frmForm.dtRelease.Value
                If frmForm.dtPlanned.Value = "" Then .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = "" Else .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = DateSerial(arDate(2), arDate(1), arDate(0))
                .Cells(emptyRow, 15) = frmForm.cmbPriority.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 16) = "Pending"
                .Cells(emptyRow, 17) = frmForm.txtRemarks.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 18) = Application.UserName

            End With
            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="password"
            'nwb.SaveAs ("sharepoint link")


            nwb.SaveAs Filename:="sharepoint link"
            nwb.Close
            'Kill ("C:\Users\username\Downloads\Planning Sheet\KF 6.0_checkout.xlsm")
            MsgBox ("Your Entry has been recorded.")
        End If
    End If
    Unload frmForm
End Sub
```

Sorry, the code is a bit messy, the strFileName, and strFileexists were checking if the checkout file exists or not, when earlier I was using the network drive. But now for sharepoint they dont work, so I replaced them with empty string

I have replaced the actual sharepoint links with the word sharepoint link in the code

Edit2: I have thought of a solution to add an error handler, so when the code cant edit the file because someone else is using it, it will throw an error and error handler will say that someone else is using the file.

This is my edited code:

```
Sub Submit()
    On Error GoTo eh
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    If frmForm.txtAE.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtAPL.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtBatches.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtProject.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtQA.Value = "" Or frmForm.txtTeam.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbDS.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbPriority.Value = "" Or frmForm.cmbRelease.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Complete All fields marked with (*) to proceed")
    Else
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim strFileExists As String
        'Call Downloadtest
        strFileName = ""
        strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)

        If strFileName <> "" Then
            MsgBox ("Another user is currently submitting a booking. Please wait for a minute, and then try again.")
        Else

            Dim nwb As Workbook
            Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("sharepoint link")

            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="password"
            Dim emptyRow As Long
            emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")) + 1

            Dim arDate As Variant
            arDate = Split(frmForm.dtPlanned.Value, "/")
            With nwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

                .Cells(emptyRow, 1) = emptyRow - 1
                .Cells(emptyRow, 2) = Date
                .Cells(emptyRow, 3) = frmForm.txtProject.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 4) = frmForm.txtTeam.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 5) = frmForm.txtAPL.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 6) = frmForm.txtQA.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 7) = frmForm.txtAE.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 8) = frmForm.cmbRelease.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 9) = frmForm.cmbDS.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 10) = frmForm.txtBatches.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 11) = frmForm.dtReview.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 12) = frmForm.dtSubmission.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 13) = frmForm.dtRelease.Value
                If frmForm.dtPlanned.Value = "" Then .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = "" Else .Cells(emptyRow, 14) = DateSerial(arDate(2), arDate(1), arDate(0))
                .Cells(emptyRow, 15) = frmForm.cmbPriority.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 16) = "Pending"
                .Cells(emptyRow, 17) = frmForm.txtRemarks.Value
                .Cells(emptyRow, 18) = Application.UserName

            End With
            nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="password"
            'nwb.SaveAs ("sharepoint link")


            nwb.SaveAs Filename:="sharepoint link"
            nwb.Close
            'Kill ("C:\Users\username\Downloads\Planning Sheet\KF 6.0_checkout.xlsm")
            MsgBox ("Your Entry has been recorded.")
        End If
    End If
    Unload frmForm
eh:
    MsgBox("Someone else using the file")
End Sub
```

Ok, now the problem is that this closes the form after showing the error, any way to prevent the closing of the form and keeping all the entries filled so that user can try hitting the submit button again after few seconds?

Comment: Might help to show what happens when the user clicks "submit"

Comment: @TimWilliams I have edited the question